What's so special about the Levy distribution?
The distribution with the PDF below is a particular case of the Levy distribution.
$$f(x) = \sqrt{\frac{1}{\pi}}.\frac{e^{-\frac{1}{x}}}{x^{1.5}}$$
Someone said it was their favorite distribution. From the functional form, it seems quite unremarkable to me. There is a term in the numerator that is bounded at $1$. It could be replaced by any other bounded term. And the denominator has a polynomially decaying term which will make it a viable distribution. It could have easily been $x^2$ or any $x^\gamma$ where $\gamma > 1$.
So, what's so special about the $1.5$? Why is this distribution so famous?
One of its key characteristics seems to be that its stable. Is $\gamma= 1.5$ the only value that'll produce that property?
I guess I'm asking if there is a way to guess its special nature by its PDF?

Because it has an antiderivative you can actually compute? Use the substitution $u=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ and this is a plain Gaussian.

I'm sure there will be many $\gamma$ values in the denominator and bounded functions in the numerator that will create an integrable function. Also, your substitution produces a $u^3$ term in the numerator. Am I missing something?

$dx=du^{-2}=-2u^{-3}du$ mops that up.

Ah, this is for integrating it? How does that help though? You get another function that isn't integrable.

$du = -0.5x^{-1.5}dx$. You have the special properties backwards. The boundedness is not what makes it special, that's only what makes it a valid pdf. It's the fact that it is a simple transformation away from a Gaussian. Statisticians love their Gaussians. The ability to map a normal distribution on a data set that is organized differently cannot be understated.
